# How to export results of search on FreePatentsOnline?

Tags: search

Once I run a patent search on [FreePatentsOnline](https://www.freepatentsonline.com/), and get a list of 100+ patents, how can I export these results to a file (any format is fine: csv, Excel, etc)? Google Patents offers file export of search results, but seems to miss some patents that are found in searches by FreePatentsOnline.
Or if you use a web scraper tool for this, which one?

Comment: Perhaps use a better search site like The Lens?

Comment: Not to be flippant, but lens.org is really good and makes exporting extremely easy and flexible.

Comment: Do you find that The Lens is pretty complete in searches including recently published patents? I was happy with Google Patents until I discovered it was missing some hits that FreePatentsOnline could find.

Comment: Lens finds everything. So will Google Patents, but you need to be careful with settings. It defaults to ignoring some patents within a patent family.

Comment: When you search on Google Patents, you should see an option toward the top  of the screen that is "Deduplicate by:" defaulted to "Family". Set this to "Publication" to get a full list.

Comment: Regardless, when I search on my own patents, the Lens gets the full list more easily as I have one patent filed without my middle initial and it's easier to build the logic to include that without including others who share my first and last name.

Comment: @EricS that Deduplicate tip for Google is greatly appreciated. You have answered my question so if you want to turn your comments into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Actually, the question relates to FreePatentsOnline which I do not use as I find Google Patents and The Lens preferable. If you were to edit the question to be more generally about exporting search results to CSV, I could generate an answer to that.

Comment: I think I will leave the question as is, in case it helps someone else with FreePastentsOnline, but many thanks.