# How to export results of search on US Patent Public Search?

Tags: search

On the US patent office search site, [Patent Public Search](https://ppubs.uspto.gov/pubwebapp/), I can run a search and get many hits. How can I export these results to a file (any format is fine: csv, Excel, etc.)?
Or if you use a web scraper tool for this, which one?

Answer (score 1):

In [this](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/Patent-Public-Search-Search-results-QRG.pdf) USPTO document, step #11 explains how to copy and paste the results into Excel.

Or if you want a tab-separated CSV file to use with another application besides Excel:

1. Run your search on Patent Public Search (examples of queries [here](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/Patent-Public-Search-Search-overview-QRG.pdf)). You will get search results listed in rows.
2. Select rows to copy by checking the boxes on the left under Select. You can select all rows by clicking the first box then the last. Selected rows are shown with blue shading. Right click in the blue shading and select Copy.
3. Open a text editor and paste. Your search results will be copied in as tab separated text. Save this to a csv file and read it into Excel.

(If you are using the USPTO tool because you have found that Google Patent search results are incomplete, see Eric S's tip [here](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/25067/how-to-export-results-of-search-on-freepatentsonline) to set "Deduplicate by:" to "Publications" instead of "Family".)